# Designation for opening jquery-ui dialoge

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a situation where I want to open a modal with a button. However, it seems like I need to use an ID or CLASS for my designator. Where this gets tricky is I want my modal button to look like my other buttons, so I don't want to give it it's own CLASS or ID since either that will mean duplicating CSS or changing the way the button looks.

I have two solutions to this:

1. Put a name attibute on my a href and point my javascript to that to open the modal instead of CLASS or ID
2. Put a second empty "modal" class on my a href and point my javascript to that to open the modal

`

```
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  show: {
    effect: "blind",
    duration: 1000
  },
  hide: {
    effect: "explode",
    duration: 1000
  }
});

$( "#btn_sec" ).click(function() {
  $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
});
```

And my html:

```
<a href="#" class="btn" id="btn_sec2">Click me!</a>
```

Which is the more schemantic approach?

Comment: _I don't want to give it it's own CLASS or ID_ `ID`s must be unique anyways , what do you mean by that? And you can add plain `class`es to your element just to use it in jquery like `class="btn something something_else"` then `$( ".something" ).click()`

Comment: ^this! Why you dont use a classname simple for trigger dialogs. You dont have to style this class and nothing gets overwritten or dublicated

Comment: Ok, that is the approach I went for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second is the common approach, I believe. Elements can have multiple classes, so you can give it one class for CSS, and another class for jQuery designation.

Answer (score 1):

You can choose option of setting Listener based on ID of button if you want to open this dialog using this button only. But if you want to open same dialog using multiple buttons then ID would not work. there you can use class as designator. Same class can be added to all such buttons.